# Issues with CMake Compilation on Windows 11 - Need Assistance

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64

I am attempting to compile using CMake on Windows 11, but I am encountering persistent issues:

```
'Release' build type is used by default. Use CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to specify build type (Release or Debug)
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
The C compiler identification is unknown
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files/MinGW/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files/MinGW/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - broken
CMake Error at D:/Program Files/cmake-3.18.4-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "D:/Program Files/MinGW/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/Opencv/opencv4.5.5/sources/_output/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):D:/PROGRA~2/MinGW/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_76d6e/fast && D:/PROGRA~2/MinGW/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_76d6e.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_76d6e.dir/build

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Opencv/opencv4.5.5/sources/_output/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_76d6e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj

    D:\PROGRA~2\MinGW\mingw64\bin\G__~1.EXE    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_76d6e.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c D:\Opencv\opencv4.5.5\sources\_output\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx

    Linking CXX executable cmTC_76d6e.exe

    "D:\Program Files\cmake-3.18.4-win64-x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_76d6e.dir\link.txt --verbose=1

    %TSD-Header-###%by锟斤拷f锟斤拷锟絔锟斤拷J锟?锟?  锟?          @  锟絣3 锟? 锟紾P 锟斤拷锟?Z锟?v锟斤拷锟斤拷;_~锟揭?)b&膸锟?锟?锟?T锟絜>}锟紷_鈥诧拷F锟斤拷锟絲锟斤拷7锟斤拷|锟?4锟斤拷A锟斤拷锟絨锟斤拷锟斤拷锟?a$崭锟組?E2锟?v锟斤拷锟斤拷;_锟斤拷聻)c'锟?锟斤拷T8T锟絜.}锟紸_鈥诧拷F锟絓锟?锟斤拷7锟缴ふ?Error running link command: 绯荤粺鎵句笉鍒版寚瀹氱殑鏂囦欢銆?mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_76d6e.dir\build.make:107: cmTC_76d6e.exe] Error 2

    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Opencv/opencv4.5.5/sources/_output/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:139: cmTC_76d6e/fast] Error 2

    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:113 (enable_language)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Opencv/opencv4.5.5/sources/_output/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Opencv/opencv4.5.5/sources/_output/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Where might the issue be?

I have tried switching between different versions, but the result is always the same. There seems to be an issue with g++.exe, as I keep receiving error messages related to it.

Here are the specifics of my setup:

- Operating System: Windows 11 Professional
- CMake Version: cmake-3.18.4-win64-x64
- OpenCV Version: 4.5.5
- MinGW64: MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0

Comment: Get rid of your MinGW and reinstall both it and a prebuilt OpenCV from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: What's the error message in english?

Comment: the error message is “ g++.exe is not able to compile a simple test program.”

Comment: no, the block of chinese in the middle of the output is the actual error

Answer (score 0):

Avoid installing MinGW-w64 in paths with special characters (like spaces).

Also MinGW-w64 GCC-8.1.0 is old.
I recommend using a more recent version (e.g. from https://winlibs.com/), and this time make sure it's installed under a path without special characters (like `C:\Prog\MinGW`)